# Search index in drupal7

Tags: 7, search

I tried following methods for search index in drupal 7:

1. Click on re-index site.
2. Number of items to index per cron run is 100.
3. Save Configration.
4. Run Cron and check the items count left to index.

I got "There are no new nodes. Cron run successfully." still I am getting (0% of the site has been indexed. There are 51996 items left to index) in index status.

Answer (score 4):

if you have drush installed, you can do it this way:
 `drush search-reindex --immediate --verbose`

There is a dev module available that does the same thing.
https://drupal.org/project/reindex

It's probably a good idea to have the site in maintenance mode while you try this.

Answer (score -1):

Drupal's search engine indexes the text content of the nodes on your site. You can tweak the way it does this.

The search engine does its indexing at intervals you choose by setting "cron runs." Cron (which stands for chronograph) is not a part of Drupal. It's a scheduler that resides on your server and runs tasks (called "cron jobs") at intervals, which you specify. The jobs can run weekly, daily, hourly, or whatever you like.

you can better check [Search: an internal site search system](http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/search)

Comment: OP is not looking for this.